# How to debug when error_log not working as expected

Tags: debug, wp-debug

Trying to debug my development and running into a lot of frustrations with lack of output in the debug.log.  For example, I have this defined in wp-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );
```

I have this in my functions.php

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'my_custom_function' );
function my_custom_function( $content ){
  error_log( 'this fired' ); //never works!
  $return $content;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have a debug.log file at all? Please check the `/wp-content/` directory.

Comment: Yes I see deprecated/notice errors and can clear them and see them come right back, just can't manually debug my own work.

Comment: Disabled speed of light caching plugin and now I am seeing my debugs, whew.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After disabling all plugins I was able to narrow down which one was affecting the log output.  The client had installed Speed of Light plugin to provide caching and compression which was also effecting wp_debug capabilities.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer.